# PHP: include function is blocked

Tags: php, include

My PHP files are not able to call the include function anymore. I suppose my hosting changed php settings. Is there any workaround to this problem? Can I enable the include function in php.ini/.htaccess files? How? My host is using PHP version 4.4.9.

EDIT - All the files that I am trying to include are local files and not files on another server. The include functions were working fine until a few days back. They have suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Are you trying to include local files, or remote files from another website?

Comment: Without more information we are not going to be able to provide you with a solution.

Comment: @Gaurav - That still isn't enough information to get a decent answer. What does "stopped working" mean - do you get an error?

Comment: I do not know if i get an error as my host has disabled error displays. All I need to know is that if my host has disabled include function support, is there a workaround? Can I use cURL or make an entry in .htaccess etc to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

i think is permission problem,

do you see error in error log file ,

or see error in the screen ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your host changed the path to your www.

Are you using relative or absolute paths in your include()?

Comment: the file that I need to include is in the same directory as the file calling it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks and feels wrong, but could this work?

```
function includeFile($path) {

    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        return false;
    }

    $contents = file_get_contents($path);

    eval($contents); // ewww
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Might be worth a try strictly for testing purposes.. but this type of code should never touch production.

Comment: PS: if $path is a url, it will be eval()ed already so the second eval() could produce unexpected results.

Comment: Yeah I realise it's awful, but it's worth a *try*. Though I'd hate to see this make production (I'd be getting include/require enabled again)